# No upload button for chat on mobile site

Tags: bug, chat

Many times I use SO chat from mobile website. Recently the site has been upgraded. Older version was not having the upload button but I was surprised that the newer version also doesn't have it! (at least I couldn't find it)

I do have the privilege because it appears on desktop site. What could be the problem?

Comment: [Add upload image button to the new mobile chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276085/add-upload-image-button-to-the-new-mobile-chat)